# Проблема подключения telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon, raspberry-pi

Написал небольшой скрипт на питоне который подключается к моему аккаунуту в Telegram и в определенное время отсылает сообщения в один чат. Поставил на Raspberry Pi в качестве сервера и сутки все работало отлично, но сегодня с утра скрипт подключиться не смог. зависает на строке

```
 client.start()
```

Тестовый пример в виде подключения и отправки сообщения так же зависает на этой строке

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync
import datetime,schedule,time

api_id = 24xxxxx
api_hash = '59b23dd463xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
client = TelegramClient('MyReports', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()

def sendReport():
    client.send_message(-403554xxxxx, 'Тестовое сообщение от бота ' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S'))


sendReport()
schedule.every().hours.at(":00").do(sendReport)
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Пробовал тот же скрипт запускать с ПК. Результат - та же ошибка что и на Raspberry

```
Server closed the connection: 0 bytes read on a total of 8 expected bytes
```

Время на сервере верное, модули обновлены. Куда смотреть и что делать?